# Is there a way to programatically get the FeatureClass's alias name?

Tags: arcobjects

I'd like to get the alias name of a FeatureClass, but I can't find an interface  exposing that field.

UPDATE:

using [IClassSchemaEdit](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_cpp/componenthelp/index.html#/IClassSchemaEdit_Interface/000s000000tr000000/), I'm able to specify an alias name, but I'm still unable to retreive it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [IFeatureClass](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002qs000000) Interface exposes the AliasName.

Comment: too simple... I was looking in the dataset, alongside the name and the browsename... Thanks